# Spring security exclude endpoint from custom filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

Having a spring security configuration with:

```
http.antMatcher("/**/v1/public/company/employees/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**/v1/public/company/employees/A").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/v1/public/company/employees/B").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/v1/public/company/employees/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .addFilterBefore(customFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
```

How I can exclude public endpoints (**A** and **B**) from `customFilter`?

**Update**

Using:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**/v1/public/company/employees/A")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/v1/public/company/employees/B")
        }
```

seems enough, but I still don't know if it's the recommended way

Comment: So you basically have three endpoints - is that correct? Two of them that are publicly available and the other one(s) that do require authentication?

Comment: Well I'm using `/**` for my endpoints which needs authentication, so there are a lot of endpoints there. The number of endpoints is important? Because I'm looking for the general approach.

Comment: One solution could be to create separate http-security configs for the endpoints A and B. This means that you end up with 2 additional security configs.

Comment: I think you can follow this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-exclude-filter